# Routing did not work properly in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am currently doing a project called Doctor Management System.In this project I am stuck because my route did not work correctly.Whenevr I have to go on a specific id it gives me Gibberish id.
My Route file is

```
Route::get('/district/hospital/hospital_info/{id}', array('as' =>'hospital_info' ,'uses' => 'UserController@hospital_info'));
```

My Controller is

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Division;
use App\District;
use App\Category;
use App\Dcategory;
use App\Hospital;
use App\Doctor;
class UserController extends Controller
{


        public function hospital_info($id)
        {
            $divisions = Division::all();
             $division=Division::find($id); 

             $district=District::find($id); 
             $category=Category::find($id);
             $hospital=Hospital::find($id);


            return view('users.hospital_info')
                        ->with('divisions',  $divisions)
                        ->with('division', $division)
                        ->with('district', $district)
                        ->with('category',$category)
                        ->with('hospital',$hospital);
        }
```

My view file is

```
<?php $active="hospital"; ?>
```

@extends('layouts.dashboard')
@section('content')

```
<section id="feature" class="transparent-bg">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="center wow fadeInDown">
            <h2>Renowned Hospital in {{ $district->name }}</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="features">
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
                    <div class="feature-wrap">
                        <h2>{{ $category->name }}</h2>
                        <h3><a  href="{!! URL::route('hospital_info') !!}"> View Details</a></h3>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.col-md-4-->
                @endforeach


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

@stop

The error is:

[image]

Here You can see I did not find the id. But If I staticly Give the id it shows the Info. I don't find where the problem is. Please help me solving this.

Comment: in the view, you aren't using the route that you have given as in the routes. Please give relevant file. __This view file does not have that route i.e. route('hospital_info')__

Comment: I update my code. Please have a look @itachi

Comment: When I give value staticly it gives me my required output.If I have lack of correct data then when i give static url then how does it gives me output. @Mojtaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write this in your controller

```
public function hospital_info($id)
    {
        $divisions = Division::all();
         $division=Division::find($id); 

         $district=District::find($id);
         $categories=Category::all(); 
         $category=Category::find($id);
         $hospital=Hospital::find($id);
         // $hospitals =$hospital->paginate(5);
         $hospitals = Hospital::where('district_id',$id)->paginate(2);


         $doctor=User::find($id);
         $doctors = User::where('district_id',$id)->paginate(1);
        // $districts=District::where('division_id', '=', $divisions->id)->get();

        // if (!$district)
        // {
        //     throw new NotFoundHttpException;
        // }
        return view('users.hospital_info')
                    ->with('divisions',  $divisions)
                    ->with('division', $division)
                    ->with('district', $district)
                    ->with('categories',$categories)
                    ->with('category',$category)
                    ->with('hospital',$hospital)
                    ->with('hospitals',$hospitals)
                    ->with('doctor',$doctor)
                    ->with('doctors',$doctors);
    }
```

And in your view file you should write

```
<?php $active="hospital"; ?>
@extends('layouts.dashboard')
@section('content') 

    <section id="feature" class="transparent-bg">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="center wow fadeInDown">
                <h2>Renowned Hospital in {{ $district->name }}</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="features">
                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
                        <div class="feature-wrap">
                            <h2>{{ $category->name }}</h2>
                            <h3><a  href="{!! URL::route('hospital_info',$district['id']) !!}"> View Details</a></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/.col-md-4-->
                    @endforeach


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@stop
```

Comment: Thank you sir. You helped me solving my three problem. would you help me solving the other problem in this project?

Comment: What kind of problem? @Masuma Sultana

Comment: I have two other question in my profile. Would you please help me solving this

Comment: I try my level best @Masuma Sultana

Answer (score 1):

You are using `{id}` in your URL, this should be replaced by the integer id. For example your URL should be `http://localhost/doctor_info/public/district/hospital/hospital_info/1`

Comment: `{id}` is dynamic. It comes from client side. You suggest to make it static.

Comment: Yes but the screenshot with the error you are using it as {id}. This is why you are receiving this error from server

Comment: Then what I shoul be write to make it dynamic @aldrin27

Comment: in the screenshot when i got to the url it does not find the id so that it just print the {id}. This is my problem. How can i find the id dynamically?

Comment: @JahidMahmud when you write the URL in browser it should be the same as I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: then what should be if i want to write `http://localhost/doctor_info/public/district/hospital/hospital_info/2`. I want to act it dynamically. But it did not act dynamically. It acted well when i give id to staticly. How can i did it dynamically @Mina Abadir

Comment: Don't change anything on server side. Only the URL you call.

Comment: then how can i change my URL dynamically @Mina Abadir

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to achieve. What do you mean by changing it dynamically